# Justifying content responsively in 100% height section (flexbox?)

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox, justify

I'm new to coding and I'm making a responsive one-page scroller using bootstrap. Each section is height:100%, so it changes based on the size of the window. 
I'd like to know how to justify my content so it's centered vertically in the window as well as has equal space between the different objects in the section. I've tried doing this with flexbox, but it's not working out. I'm open to using css, flexbox, or js.

Thank you in advance!

This is a simplified version of what my code is for each section:

```css
name {
  height:100%;
}
```

```html
<section class="name">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <h1 class="col-xs-12">Header</h1>
      <p class="col-xs-12">Info</p>
      
      <img class="col-xs-12" src="-">
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this it may help: (css)

```
name {
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
display: block;
}
```